# Add offers in google wallet via API

Tags: php, api, android-pay

Now I elaborate my question, I want to make offer on my own site and send it to google wallet for add. I haven't found any API for add offers in google wallet. If you guys know about it please tell me.
**Your suggestions and links definitely considerable.**

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Wallet recently launched a Wallet Offers API.

You can find API documentation, tutorials, code samples on the developer site:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/objects/

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/objects/offers/offers-flows

Also relevant: Google I/O 2013 talk - *Digitizing The Entire Wallet: Introducing Wallet Objects*.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvZsFw8D_8c

Comment: Well, Thank you. Can you please tell me more. Is it necessary "Sign up for Wallet Objects API access" ? I am using it for testing purpose .. I mean how it is work.

Comment: Yes, at this time a sign-up with Google is required. Generally it takes 2 days to receive a reply back.